# Convert an Object to a user defined type class object without Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, reflection

I have the following code where i am adding some class objects in an Array.

```
  Object[] ArrayOfObjects = new Object[] {typeof(Person), typeof(Company)};
```

Now if i want to iterate through my class items, how can i convert each item back to its original Type (such as Person and Company)? This might be possible using Reflection but i want to find out if C# has some built in functionality to achieve this.

```
  foreach (var item in ArrayOfObjects)
  {
     // TODO Convert item back to Original Type (Person or Company)
     // I am doing something like this but not working
     var person  =  Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(Person));

     //I can not do this too as hardcoding the type inside the loop makes no sense
     var person = item as Person; //I need to convert item as Person or Company so that i can automate the tasks here.
  }
```

Much Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to convert it back to its type - it already **is** that type. The runtime type of the object (e.g. `Person`) and the type of the variable (e.g. `System.Object`) aren't the same thing.

Comment: Please show us __what you are trying to do__ - since the question as is feels like a [mcve]. In other words - show us some sample TODO code showing how you plan to _use_ the `Person` or `Company`.

Comment: I _suspect_ what you want is `var person  =  item as Person;` Then check if it is `null`. Or alternatively `foreach (var item in ArrayOfObjects.OfType<Person>())`.

Comment: @mjwills what do you mean by it already is that type? please add more.

Comment: I mean **if it is a person** you don't need to `ChangeType` to a person. It already is one (i.e. if you called `item.GetType()` it would return `Person`). So if `item` is a person then `var person  =  item as Person;` will work just fine.

Comment: @mjwills i can not do item as Person. because with this there is no point writing this in a loop. i have many objects that need to be automated to do some task. is there a way where i can convert it into type inside the loop?

Comment: Be careful of the words you are using here. Do you need to process each item and create a new instance of another type? Or do you simply need a variable of the correct type so that you can refer to it? Depending on your answer `if (item is Person person){...} else if(item is Company company){...}` may be sufficient.

Comment: However your example `new Object[] {typeof(Person), typeof(Company)};` is doing something else. This is an array of Type objects, not instances of each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some assumptions about your use case, you might benefit from using an interface to eliminate the need to convert the objects at all

Say you need to do the shared method Foo which belongs to both Company and Person

```
public interface ObjectWithFoo{
     void Foo();
}
public class Person : ObjectWithFoo{
    ...
}
public class Company: ObjectWithFoo{
    ...
}
```

Then in your main code you create a list of ObjectWithFoo

```
ObjectWithFoo[] myArray = new ObjectWithFoo[]{new Person(), new Company()}
```

And then in your loop

```
foreach(var objectWithFoo in myArray)
    objectWithFoo.Foo();
```

This way you don't need to cast at all, you can just use use the interface for everything. The added benefit is that it becomes more clear what your array is meant to be used for to yourself and others - it is used for only methods/attributes belonging to your interface. If you use an array of objects people can easily add an unsupported type or start using the list elsewhere and make your code a bit chaotic.

Comment: I'd suggest making `I` the first letter of your interface name.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
using System;

namespace PatternMatching
{
    class Person
    {
        public void PersonMethod() => throw new Exception();
    }

    class Company
    {
        public void CompanyMethod() => throw new Exception();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object[] ArrayOfObjects = { new Person(), new Company() };

            foreach (var item in ArrayOfObjects)
            {
                if (item is Person person)
                {
                    person.PersonMethod();
                }

                if (item is Company company)
                {
                    company.CompanyMethod();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use pattern matching (C# 8.0+)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0
You can use even switch pattern for that.

Comment: Let's say i have 50 object, This is i would be adding 50 if statements?

Comment: If you have 50 objects you want to treat this way means that your design is shitty and needs refactoring (50% kidding now). As I told, you can use switch statement, but there are some restrictions now.

Comment: How can a design be shitty for having 50 objects in a loop?

Comment: I thought you mean 50 different class types. Not a good idea, I think, to use Object[] for operating all of them. But if you mean just loop through ~50 objects of 3-5 class types - it is solution of course, but you MUST avoid it.